# Laravel Inertia-React share function with parameters

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, global, inertiajs

In Inertia I know I can share datas via HandleInertiaRequests middleware, can I share a function that gets arguments?

Below code (dummy code) gives the error: `TypeError: can is not a function`

```php
'can' => fn($query = false) => $user->hasPermissionTo($query)
```

I tried IIFE

```php
'can' => (function($query) 
         {
            $user->hasPermissionTo($query)
         })()
```